# 2 websites under one domain

Tags: database, multi-sites

In one domain I want 2 drupal it as follows:
www.example.com/index.php (not necessarily drupal), just a landing page 
On the index page people have to chose between 2 Drupal Sites

www.example.com/salloon1/index.php
or
www.example.com/salloon2/index.php

Can I do this ass follow?
**Step 1**
Uploading all drupal files to www.example.com/saloon1/
Create Database saloon1_DB
settings.php pointing to saloon1_DB
**Step 2**
Uploading all drupal files to www.example.com/saloon2/
Create Database saloon2_DB
settings.php pointing to saloon2_DB

index.php
2 images: image 1 pointing to www.example.com/saloon1/index.php
          image 2 pointing to www.example.com/saloon2/index.php

Is this right or is there another solution?

Thanks guys in advance!!
Best regards,
Pieter-Jan Derks

Answer (score 0):

One way to create multiple sites within one drupal instance is to use the domain access module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

Using this you can create different sites with different domains on the same instance. You won't be able to do www.example.com/saloon1 and www.example.com/saloon2 (unless you use the subfolder domain module that extends domain access. Though I'm having trouble getting that module to work)
But you could do saloon1.example.com or saloon2.example.com or you could do saloon1.com and saloon2.com

On all content and blocks you'd be able to specify whether it's available to one domain, the other, or both. You could also restrict user privileges to one domain. You could also apply different themes to each domain.

Comment: Thanks fot the answer! It will help me and I am going tho think for the right solution!!